# How do I display an error message if there is no valid result matching the search?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a search bar and this is my JavaScript code so far:

```
function search_product() {
var searchbar, filter, cards, card, h1, i, txtValue;
searchbar = document.getElementById('searchbar');
filter = searchbar.value.toUpperCase();
cards = document.getElementById("cards");
card = cards.getElementsByClassName('card');

searchbar.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();

        for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
            h1 = card[i].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
            txtValue = h1.textContent || h1.innerText;

            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                card[i].style.display = "";
            }

            else {
                card[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
})
}
```

Basically searching for the content of the h1 tag.
Everything works fine, but I want to add an error message if there are no matching results, so I just made this HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<div class="search-results" id="search-results">
        <h1>No results found.</h1>
        <p>That resource does not exist.</p>
        <img src="../img/icons/animated/passaros.gif">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.search-results {
    background-color: #131313;
    height: 48vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    display: none;
}

.search-results h1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.search-results p {
    margin: 0;
    color: #cccccc;
}
```

And made it hidden.
I know how to make it a block using JS:

```
document.getElementById("search-results").style.display = "block";
```

But I don't know where to put this line in the JS, because in the first "if" I basically check if the input is empty and make all the cards re-appear if it is, and in the "else" return the matching results.

Thx to anyone that helps in advance.

Comment: Several ways to do this, but with your  current code, probably simplest way is count how many times you "find something"  check if count is  larger than zero at the end. Show your message accordingly, and reset the count again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to identify no result found, as per your code, simplest way to add with a flag, let's say flag name `resultFound` like

```
   var resultFound;
   for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        h1 = card[i].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
        txtValue = h1.textContent || h1.innerText;

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            resultFound = true;
            card[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            card[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if(resultFound) {
        document.getElementById("search-results").style.display = "";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("search-results").style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: This worked, tysm!!

Answer (score 0):

why not declare the variable for search-results and add an if statement inside the for loop!